# ngx-bootstrap 7: BsDropdownModule error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I use ngx-bootstrap version 6.x, when trying to update to 7.x I get the following error:

```
Error: Error: src/app/app.module.ts:41:30 - error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

41     BsDropdownModule.forRoot({ isAnimated: false, autoClose: true }),
```

how am I supposed to set the configuration for the `BsDropdownModule` in version 7.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [BsDropdownModule](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/95f72441b4736bc4b7363026c3ce013e43b35e11/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.module.ts), `forRoot()` doesn't have argument.

Hence, you have to **remove the argument from `BsDropdownModule.forRoot()`**.

To override the default `BsDropdownState` value, you have to inject [`BsDropdownConfig`](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.config.ts) to `providers` for `AppModule` or `Component`.

```js
import { BsDropdownConfig, BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

export const BS_DROPDOWN_CUSTOM = {
  isAnimated: false,
  autoClose: true
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: BsDropdownConfig,
      useValue: BS_DROPDOWN_CUSTOM
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jhgir3?file=app/app.module.ts)

---

**Note:** You may not need to inject `BsDropdownConfig` into `providers` as the default value (`BsDropdownState`) is the same as your provided config.

> [bs-dropdown.module.ts](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/95f72441b4736bc4b7363026c3ce013e43b35e11/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.module.ts)

```js
export class BsDropdownModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<BsDropdownModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: BsDropdownModule,
      providers: [
        ComponentLoaderFactory,
        PositioningService,
        BsDropdownState
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

> [bs-dropdown.state.ts](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/src/dropdown/bs-dropdown.config.ts)

```js
export class BsDropdownState {
  direction: 'down' | 'up' = 'down';
  autoClose = true;
  insideClick = false;
  isAnimated = false;

  ...
}
```